# Reverse engineering: Why is there a PD IC in this Adapter?

Tags: charger, charging, usb-c, usb-pd

I have a question regarding an Ethernet and USB-C(PD) to USB-C Adapter:

[image]

Amazon-Link: [https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Charging-Thunderbolt-Chromecast-Chromebook/dp/B09MTN8ZT3/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1BO8X4NEO31BY&keywords=ruxley+ethernet&qid=1661867165&sprefix=ruxely+ethern%2Caps%2C315&sr=8-3#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09MTN8ZT3)

I opened it up and to my surprise I discovered a VL102-Controller that controls the power of both USB-C ports. In my understanding of the USB-C connector it would be sufficient to make the cable just passive and to connect the VBUS and CC lines directly between the two usb jacks with no in-between circuitry. But this assumption does not seem to be true because otherwise the manufacturer of the adapter would not have decided to add this IC. I'd be grateful if anybody could tell me why this PD IC is needed.

Comment: It's not just a PD but also DP adapter for video.

Comment: I don't think so, in the amazon-description they state that the male usb-c-port can't be used to output video [link] (https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Charging-Thunderbolt-Chromecast-Chromebook/dp/B09MTN8ZT3/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1BO8X4NEO31BY&keywords=ruxley+ethernet&qid=1661867165&sprefix=ruxely+ethern%2Caps%2C315&sr=8-3#customerReviews)

Comment: Right , only Google Chromecast videos

Answer (score 1):

This adapter does three things:

- Power routing through, from Type-C Receptacle to Type-C plug,
- USB2 data passthrough from Type-C Receptacle to Type-C plug,
- Thunderbolt-3 alternate mode with a TB3 Ethernet adapter internally connected.

Logically, two Type-C port controllers are needed (one for each Type-C, even if they can be actually implemented by a single chip, as VL102 does):

- One on UFP (here, the plug) to negotiate both TB3 Alternate mode, detect orientation and negotiate power source contract to UFP,
- One on DRP (here, the receptacle) to negotiate power contract with PD power supply, or supply VBUS for devices.